# How can get comment link by comment id?

Tags: comments

How can get the comment link by using comment id?

I trying to search on google but I can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`get_comment_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_link/).

Here's an example from the `wp-cli` shell:

```
$ wp shell
wp> echo get_comment_link( 4 );
https://example.com/2018/04/12/hello-world/comment-page-1/#comment-4
```